# Rich text editor in popups

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

How can I configure the WYSISYG editor in popups?
I am using the [TinyMCE](http://drupal.org/project/tinymce) module; in visibility I have added the page, but the rich text editor will be visible only on the pages, not in the popups.

I included the popup path and used wildcards, but it still doesn't come up in popups (I am using Thickbox)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What version of Drupal and TinyMCE are you using? When you say "popups" do you mean "overlay"?